# Using SQL parameters to DROP INDEX in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to follow best practice (and also remove Visual Studio Code Analysis warnings) by using parameters when dropping a SQL Server index.

Not using parameters works fine:

```
string tableName = "dbo.TableName";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DROP INDEX Blah ON " + tableName);

sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

However, when I try to use a parameter I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near '@TableName'.

Code:

```
string tableName = "dbo.TableName";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DROP INDEX Blah ON @TableName");

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("TableName", tableName));

sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it need to be "@TableName"?

Comment: @EricJ. `SqlParameter` will automatically add the `@` if it is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong.  Parameters cannot be used to replace identifiers -- column names/aliases, table names/aliases, schema names, and database names. They also cannot be used to replace function names or operators or keywords.

That is a long list.  They can be used to replace constants in the query.

I guess the way to remember this is that the parameterized query can be pre-compiled.  In order to compile a query, all object references need to be resolved -- so the values cannot be provided by parameters.

You have already solved the problem by putting the table in the string.  You can use `quotename()` to help protect against injection (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)).

Answer (score 3):

DROP INDEX is a [DDL statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848799.aspx), most DDL statements don't accept parameterized values. The best you can do is use dynamically constructed SQL and escape the table name using [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)

```
string tableName = "dbo.TableName";

string sql = @"
declare @sql nvarchar(500)
set @sql = N'DROP INDEX Blah ON ' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
exec sp_executesql @sql
";

SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("");

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@TableName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = tableName;

sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I also updated your code to use the more "normal" way to add a parameter, explicitly setting the datatype of the parameter.